# How to fix `java.io.IOException: invalid manifest format (Webservice)` with Wildfly 10?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly-10, manifest.mf

```
17:38:34,739 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."axiswebservice.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."axiswebservice.war".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "axiswebservice.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)`enter code here`
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0161: Failed to get manifest for deployment "/content/axiswebservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/axis-sdk-1.0.jar"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.getManifest(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.deploy(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:65)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid manifest format
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:225)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:69)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.readManifest(VFSUtils.java:243)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.getManifest(VFSUtils.java:227)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.getManifest(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:76)
    ... 7 more
17:38:34,746 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management task-2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: (undefined) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"axiswebservice.war\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"axiswebservice.war\".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"axiswebservice.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0161: Failed to get manifest for deployment \"/content/axiswebservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/axis-sdk-1.0.jar\"
```

My `MANIFEST.MF` file:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>   Specification-Title: Axis Bank :: Corporate Connectivity Solution
>   Class-Path: lib4/bcmail-jdk14-145.jar lib4/bcprov-ext-jdk14-145.jar li
>     b4/bcprov-jdk14-145.jar lib4/jsch-0.1.44.jar
>   Created-By: (Axis Bank-IT,Salil Diwakar)
>   Main-Class: com.axis.enc.AxisEncryption
>   Implementation-Title: Corporate Connectivity Solution
>  
>   Specification-Vendor: Salil Diwakar,Axis Bank-IT.
>   Specification-Version: 1.0
>   Implementation-Version: 1.0
>   Name: Axis Bank
>   
>   ?

While running project on local environment no error coming and when I tried to deploy on testing server (Rhel) Wildfly 10 it is giving error.